# Formatting any string to string "yyyy/MM/dd"

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I have many strings like "20120117" and "20120321". I need to convert it in a new string with this format: "2012/01/17" and "2012/03/21". So, there is a way to do this?

I try:

```
string dateString = string.format("{0:d", "20120321");
```

and

```
string dateString = string.format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd", "20120321");
```

and

```
string dateString = int.Parse("20120321").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

I all cases i don't reach my goal. =/

So, i can i do this?

OBS: There is a way to do that without parse to datetime?

Comment: I can't code up an answer right now but if you don't like the DateTime.Parse answers I would consider writing a regex or even using substring.

Comment: I think something like this:
Regex.Replace("20120117","(?<y>\d{4})(?<m>\d{2})(?<d>\d{2})","${y}/${m}/${d}")

Comment: it doesn't look like a duplicate

Comment: @row1 now you have two problems! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to parse those values in `DateTime` objects first.

Example :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20120321", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var result = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

---

Edit after your comments on other answers:
if you don't like parsing because it may throw excepations, you can always use `TryParse`, like this:

```
DateTime dt;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact("20120321", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
if (success)
{
    var result = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
```

---

Edit 2: Using `TryParseExact` with multiple formats:

```
DateTime dt;
string[] formats = { "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy" };

bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact("20120321", formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
if (success)
{
    var result = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

It will produce  `2012/03/21` when using "20120321" as input value, and `2012/01/01` when using `2012` as input value.

Comment: Thank you Shimrod for show me all ways to do that!

Comment: You are welcome, don't hesitate if you have further questions.

Answer (score 6):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20120321", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

You could parse the string but this method gives you validation without any extra code.  Imagine receiving "20120230", "20110229", or any other invalid date.

Comment: There is a way to do that without parse to datetime?

Answer (score 4):

From your comments:

> There is a way to do that without parse to datetime?

Yes, absolutely. If you *really* want to propagate bad data through your system rather than highlighting that it's incorrect, you could definitely use:

```
// Make sure we'll always be able to get a result whatever the input.
string paddedInput = input + "????????";
string mightBeBadWhoKnows = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",
    paddedInput.Substring(0, 4), // The year, if we're lucky
    paddedInput.Substring(4, 2), // The month, if we're lucky
    paddedInput.Substring(6, 2)); // The day, if we're lucky
```

But why *wouldn't* you want to spot the bad data?

You absolutely *should* parse the data. If you want to be able to continue after receiving bad data having taken appropriate action, use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx). If you're happy for an exception to be thrown, use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx). I'd suggest using the invariant culture for both parsing and formatting, unless you really want a culture-sensitive output.

Comment: If the input is like "2012" only? There is a way to do this using only TryParse or something like this? (yes i thought this now...)

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: It's not clear what you're asking, I'm afraid. What do you mean by "if the input is like 2012 only" - what about that situation? I would definitely use `TryParseExact` if at all possible.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: You can provide an array of string for the formats value in the `TryParseExact` method.  so you can specify "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy" or wathever value you want, if _at least_ one of this format is matching, it will work.

Comment: I posted a regex as a comment to your post, but it is ugly. ParseExact is the most elegant and correct solution. So I don't know why you wouldn't want to use it.

Comment: I was talking about if the value of the input variable was `2012` only, instead `20120321`. Anyway, thank you! =) +1 to you! ^^ I saw that doesn't exist a better way to do that without `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` of the Datetime class.

Comment: @JonSkeet Jon Can you help me please here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980568/row-number-over-partition-by-xxx-in-linq/9980784#9980784

Answer (score 3):

Use DateTime.ParseExact to convert to a DateTime, then use ToString on that instance to format as you desire.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

EDIT: using Insert:
EDIT2: Fixed bugs :-)

```
var newString = dateString.Insert(4, "/").Insert(7, "/");
```

Comment: There is a way to do that without parse to datetime?

Comment: You could use string.Substring() to do it, but I'd suggest this is the most robust way

Comment: the last index is 7 (string is immutable)

Comment: Whoops, Insert is an instance method, not static.  See answer from @Guffa

Comment: @AdrianIftode Yeah, just checking you are paying attention.  Always write the tests first...!  Answer from Guffa addresses this bug!

Comment: @Guffa's answer is nicer because he/she started with the last index :P, so no worries

Comment: @AdrianIftode agree, but for future visitors I fixed the bugs :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use string operations to insert the slashes:

```
string input = "20120321";

string dateString =
  input.Substring(0, 4) + "/" +
  input.Substring(4, 2) + "/" +
  input.Substring(6);
```

or

```
string dateString = input.Insert(6, "/").Insert(4, "/");
```

Comment: If the input is like "2012" only? There is a way to do this using only TryParse or something like this? (yes i thought this now...)

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: You can just check the length to catch that case: `if (input.length == 4) { dateString = input + "/01/01" } else { dateString = ...`

Answer (score 1):

If it's a date, try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20120321","yyyyMMdd", null).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
string dateString = DateTime.ParseExact("20120321", "yyyyMMdd",
                              null).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always in the same format and if you don't need to validate it, you can use the following snippet to avoid parsing it with DateTime

```
var strWithInsert =  input.Insert(4,"/").Insert(7,"/");
```