# Case insensitive group on multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there anyway to do a LINQ2SQL query doing something similar to this:

```
var result = source.GroupBy(a => new { a.Column1, a.Column2 });
```

or

```
var result = from s in source
             group s by new { s.Column1, s.Column2 } into c
             select new { Column1 = c.Key.Column1, Column2 = c.Key.Column2 };
```

but with ignoring the case of the contents of the grouped columns?

Comment: This doesn't work?  `a => {Column1 = a.Column1.ToLower(), Column2 = a.Column2.ToLower()}`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can pass `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to the `GroupBy` extension method.

```
var result = source.GroupBy(a => new { a.Column1, a.Column2 }, 
                StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Or you can use `ToUpperInvariant` on each field as suggested by [Hamlet Hakobyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685467/hamlet-hakobyan) on comment. I recommend `ToUpperInvariant` or `ToUpper` rather than `ToLower` or `ToLowerInvariant` because it is optimized for programmatic comparison purpose.

Comment: A `StringComparer` can't compare instances of anonymous types, only strings. A new comparer implementation is needed (See Bill B's answer)

Comment: @fubo this is a wrong solution, because "Column1" and "Column2" yields the same key value as "Colu" and "mn1Column2" when concatenated.

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get NaveenBhat's solution to work, getting a compile error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

To make it work, I found it easiest and clearest to define a new class to store my key columns (GroupKey), then a separate class that implements IEqualityComparer (KeyComparer). I can then call

```
var result= source.GroupBy(r => new GroupKey(r), new KeyComparer());
```

The KeyComparer class does compare the strings with the InvariantCultureIgnoreCase comparer, so kudos to NaveenBhat for pointing me in the right direction.

Simplified versions of my classes:

```
private class GroupKey
{
    public string Column1{ get; set; }
    public string Column2{ get; set; }

    public GroupKey(SourceObject r) {
        this.Column1 = r.Column1;
        this.Column2 = r.Column2;
    }
}

private class KeyComparer: IEqualityComparer<GroupKey>
{

    bool IEqualityComparer<GroupKey>.Equals(GroupKey x, GroupKey y)
    {
        if (!x.Column1.Equals(y.Column1,StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) return false;
        if (!x.Column2.Equals(y.Column2,StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) return false;
        return true;
        //my actual code is more complex than this, more columns to compare
        //and handles null strings, but you get the idea.
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<GroupKey>.GetHashCode(GroupKey obj)
    {
        return 0.GetHashCode() ; // forces calling Equals
        //Note, it would be more efficient to do something like
        //string hcode = Column1.ToLower() + Column2.ToLower();
        //return hcode.GetHashCode();
        //but my object is more complex than this simplified example

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just type `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` (which is an enum) instead of `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` (which is a class)?

Comment: You are correct, @dav_i, that's the source of the "cannot convert from 'System.StringComparison'..." error I received. However, even when I don't make that mistake a different compile error was thrown. I've updated my answer to reflect the issue encountered and rationale for this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue grouping by the values of DataRow objects from a Table, but I just used .ToString() on the DataRow object to get past the compiler issue, e.g.

```
MyTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
    dataRow => dataRow["Value"].ToString(),
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

instead of

```
MyTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
    dataRow => dataRow["Value"],
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Could not see where the *multiple columns* are.

Answer (score 1):

I've expanded on Bill B's answer to make things a little more dynamic and to avoid hardcoding the column properties in the `GroupKey` and `IQualityComparer<>`.

```
private class GroupKey
{
    public List<string> Columns { get; } = new List<string>();

    public GroupKey(params string[] columns)
    {
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            // Using 'ToUpperInvariant()' if user calls Distinct() after 
            // the grouping, matching strings with a different case will 
            // be dropped and not duplicated
            Columns.Add(column.ToUpperInvariant());
        }
    }

}

private class KeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<GroupKey>
{

    bool IEqualityComparer<GroupKey>.Equals(GroupKey x, GroupKey y)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!x.Columns[i].Equals(y.Columns[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<GroupKey>.GetHashCode(GroupKey obj)
    {
        var hashcode = obj.Columns[0].GetHashCode();

        for (var i = 1; i < obj.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var column = obj.Columns[i];

            // *397 is normally generated by ReSharper to create more unique hash values
            // So I added it here
            // (do keep in mind that multiplying each hash code by the same prime is more prone to hash collisions than using a different prime initially)
            hashcode = (hashcode * 397) ^ (column != null ? column.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }

        return hashcode;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var result = source.GroupBy(r => new GroupKey(r.Column1, r.Column2, r.Column3), new KeyComparer());
```

This way, you can pass any number of columns into the `GroupKey` constructor.