# How to convert SQL into Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get this sql statement into Linq format with no success.  Instead of displaying all data, i want to display ten items from each category.  Any help would be great.

```
select *
from (
     select *,
             row_number() over(partition by T.category order by T.id desc) as rn
 from clothes as T
 ) as T
where T.rn <= 10;
```

my attempt at linq is below;

```
var query= from (subquery) as DB in dataContext.table where DB.rn <=10;
               select DB;
var subquery = row_number() over(partition by DB.id order by DB.category desc) as rn from DB in dataContext.table as DB
                    select DB;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Row\_number over (Partition by xxx) in Linq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980568/row-number-over-partition-by-xxx-in-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `GroupBy`, `Take` and a `SelectMany` should do the trick

```
var result = dataContext.table.GroupBy(m => m.category)
             .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(10));
```