# convert SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER to linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

How to convert this request to *Linq* to get a date and a row number from table?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Row, 
       Date, 
       WebUrlReferer
 FROM [Cnx].[dbo].[Action]
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980568/row-number-over-partition-by-xxx-in-linq

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = youContext.Action
            .Select((x, i) => new
                              {
                                  Row = i,
                                  Date = x.Date,
                                  WebUrlReferer = x.WebUrlReferer
                              }) 
            .OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

Comment: stupid question ? does i `auto`increment?