# SQL Query to fetch the records with success status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below. Daily 3 different files will run and status will be inserted into the table as Success/Failure. I need all the 3 files with status success and fetch that date. Here as per below table SQL query has to return Date 2020-02-25 (as all 3 files on that are a success)

Please help me with the Query, I tried many queries but not able to get the desired result.

```
ID  Pipeline_name   Status      UpdatedDate
1   Student_Dump    SUCCESS     2020-02-27
2   Teacher_Dump    SUCCESS     2020-02-27
3   Subjects_Dump   Failed      2020-02-27  
4   Student_Dump    SUCCESS     2020-02-26
5   Teacher_Dump    Failed      2020-02-26
6   Subjects_Dump   SUCCESS     2020-02-26  
7   Student_Dump    SUCCESS     2020-02-25
8   Teacher_Dump    SUCCESS     2020-02-25
9   Subjects_Dump   SUCCESS     2020-02-25
```

Comment: You can use `RowNumber()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63c8d069d5fa2baca88453f5a349acec)

You can use `Rownumber()` to achieve it

```
Select ID,Pipeline_name,Status,UpdatedDate
from
(
  select *,row_number() over(partition by Status,UpdatedDate order by id) as rn
  from #table1
)A where rn=3 and Status = 'SUCCESS'
```

**Updated**

If you need the latest data date only, you can select `TOP 1` combines with `ORDER BY ID DESC`

```
Select TOP 1 ID,Pipeline_name,Status,UpdatedDate
from
(
  select *,row_number() over(partition by Status,UpdatedDate order by id) as rn
  from #table1
)A where rn=3 and Status = 'SUCCESS'
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

[**Output here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec758d6de5de75a7323a12cd3d33e63c)

Comment: The above Query works. Thanks for the details.

now i added below datas into the exisiting. This is added as per my data available in my table.

Now after running the query 2 records it gives. but i need the latest data date only.


(10, 'Student_Dump', 'SUCCESS', '2020-02-19'),
(11, 'Teacher_Dump', 'FAILED', '2020-02-19'),
(12, 'Teacher_Dump', 'SUCCESS', '2020-02-19'),
(13, 'Subjects_Dump', 'SUCCESS', '2020-02-19'),

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @Praveen Kumar

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
WITH cteStatus AS(
  SELECT UpdatedDate, Status, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UpdatedDate, Status ORDER BY UpdatedDate, Status) rn
    FROM T1
 )
SELECT c.UpdatedDate
  FROM cteStatus c
  WHERE Status = N'SUCCESS'
    AND rn = 3
```

The idea is to get all dates, where you have three records per Date with Status Success.

Here a link to Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a25c2b/5/1

Comment: So, what is the catch there? The data in your example looks same as before or am I missing something?

Comment: Above Query works. Now i need to convert to LINQ. Can you help me.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have a little experience with LINQ, but here might be another stack overflow thread which might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980568/row-number-over-partition-by-xxx-in-linq

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`

```
Select * from
(
  select *,row_number() over(parition by updatedate,pipeline_name order by id) as rn
  from tablename
  where status='SUCCESS'
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: This won't give the correct result - you will always get the first record per date and pipeline with Success, not the date with Success for all three pipelines... see fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a25c2b/8/1

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select UpdatedDate
from table t
group by UpdatedDate
having sum(case when statue = 'failed' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       count(distinct Pipeline_name) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select UpdatedDate from test where UpdatedDate not in 
(select UpdatedDate from test where status='Failed');
```