# Solution for complex LINQ query with ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION BY

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-core

This is my first question. For a school assignment I'm writing a program in ASP.net MVC with Rider. It is gonna be cinema webapp. The query gets the show which is played in every hall at the moment. So, for 6 halls I have 6 Id's and all of the ID's should give me back:

- HallId
- MovieTitle
- Showtime (Starttime)

The code I build was this and it works in my Query-console:

```
SELECT "HallId", "Title", "StartAt" 
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "HallId"  ORDER BY "StartAt") rn
      FROM "Showtime" where "StartAt"::time < now()::time) x
JOIN "Movie" M ON "MovieId" = M."Id"
WHERE x.rn = 1
ORDER BY "HallId"
```

I need a LINQ-query for this, but I couldn't get it working. I use Postgres by the way. That is why the “”.
Does someone has a answer for me?

Comment: I'm not aware of any LINQ query providers that support window functions. You may have exceeded the bounds of what LINQ can generate for you. Consider using a view or a stored procedure.

Comment: Well, at the moment I use the above SQL query but the problem is that I get the data from the showtime table, but it won’t return the movie table. It works in my Query Tool, I get all the needed data. But when I pass it to the View via my controller it just gives empty Movie values. I get only the Showtime values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row\_number over (Partition by xxx) in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980568/row-number-over-partition-by-xxx-in-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This was my solution:**

After a long search, I found the next (magical) solution. Works like hell for me:

```
public IEnumerable<Showtime> MovieNext(){

  return _context.Showtime
   .FromSqlRaw("SELECT tbl.* FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "HallId" ORDER BY "StartAt") row 
    FROM myDb."Showtime" 
    WHERE "StartAt" > now()) tbl 
    JOIN myDb."Movie" M ON "MovieId" = M."Id" 
    WHERE tbl.row = 1 ORDER BY "HallId"");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your question is not clear enough about the columns names but you can use the same as following linq query

```
var result = 
(from s in  dbentities.Showtime 
join r in  dbEntities.Movie on s.Mid equals r.Mid
where s.StartAt < DateTime.Now && r.rn == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: How, exactly, does that apply the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function? `rn` is synthesized in the derived table that's aliased as `x`; it's not a column in the `Showtime` table so `r.rn` won't exist.

Comment: you can use  row.SERRIA_NUMBER

Comment: Doing a google search on SERRIA_NUMBER, the question that comes up had a SERRIA_NUMBER column, so that doesn't appear to be of any use here, 1) because it doesn't exist here, and 2) because wasn't functionally equivalent to the `ROW_NUMBER` function in that other question.

Comment: refer to this you will get full idea about the row_number and partition in linq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980568/row-number-over-partition-by-xxx-in-linq

Comment: In that case, you should suggest a duplicate instead of posting an answer that doesn't work and a link that provides all the relevant details.